# Can I use the ? : syntax to decide what my method returns

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, return-value, null-coalescing-operator

I have an action method in WebAPI that executes SQL:

```
var sql = @"UPDATE UserTestQuestion
            SET    AnswerGridResponses = @AnswerGridResponses,
                   Answered = 1
            WHERE  UserTestQuestionId = @UserTestQuestionId
            AND    UserId = @UserId;";
var parameters = new SqlParameter[]
{
    new SqlParameter("@CreatedBy", createdBy),
    new SqlParameter("@AnswerGridResponses", answerGridResponses),
    new SqlParameter("@TestQuestionId", testQuestionId)
};

var rc = await db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync(sql, parameters);
if (rc > 0)
{
    return Ok(rc);
}
else
{
    return BadRequest();
}
```

It's my understanding that `ExecuteSqlCommandAsync` will return a number to 
indicate how many rows were changed. So I added a check for `rc > 0`.

Is there a way that I could do this without a need for all of the `{}`. I was 
thinking of using `?` `:` operators, but I think these only work for setting a value and not for returns like I am using.

Comment: Nope, go right ahead and use it.

Comment: You have to make sure that they're the same type and not just returning objects

Comment: it's called the ternary operator. in SQL it's like a `case when then end` statement.

Comment: What's the problem in simply returning zero? Would make sense to me if a query I made returned "0 rows queried".

Comment: I hope this is not your real code. Have EF and run plain query against it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do exactly what you want to do.

```
return (rc > 0) ? Ok(rc) : BadRequest();
```

Although some may argue using `if/else` is cleaner. You don't need curly braces, you can just do:

```
if (rc > 0)
    return Ok(rc);
else
    return BadRequest();
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have said you can definitely return the result of the ternary operator. The one thing to look out for is type conversion, as it needs to evaluate to a single return type. That really only comes up if you're trying to return null under a certain condition though, in which case you can just cast null to the correct type.

That said, it's a good idea to just assign the result to a variable and then return the variable. It's a little cleaner to read and, more importantly, easier to debug. (Essentially every time I debug one of these functions I end up changing it to a variable assignment so I can see the value before leaving the function anyway.)